# JAX-WS Change or Remove Trust Certificate Store per client instance

Tags: java, ssl, jax-ws, truststore

using JAX WS i managed to develop a web service client which is in charge to send records.
The connection with the server is trusted on SSL so i used the code below to tell the client how to manage the handshake with the server.
But now i need to be able to tell the client dynamically to choose the trust store the way that:

if i call the client with a parameter i will use cacerts1 
if i call a second client with another parameter i will use cacerts2
if i call a third client with another parameter i don t want to use any truststore

Another scenario is that:

```
Client1 ---> use Certificate1 ----> Server1

Client2 ---> use Certificate2 ----> Server1
```

Server1 uses some info inside the certificate1 and 2 to forward the message sent by client1 and client2 in 2 diff location: store1 and store2.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;    

public class MyProxy extend Service {

private static final EndOfDayService SERVICE = new EndOfDayService();

// Web service port to call services
private final MyPort port;

public MyProxy(String baseurl, SSLSocketFactory sslFactory, boolean compression) {       
    port = super.getPort(...);

    Map<String, Object> context = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
    if (baseurl != null) {
        context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, baseurl);
    }
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "pkcs12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\path\\to\\my\\cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\path\\to\\my\\cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "mypwd");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","mypwd");

    sslFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    if (sslFactory != null) {
        context.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslFactory);
    }

    // For debugging only: don't check host name in server certificate when pointing to localhost
    context.put(JAXWSProperties.HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostName, SSLSession session) {
            if (hostName.equals("localhost")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    }
}

public String record(List<EndOfDayInstance> records) throws SystemFaultException, UserFaultException {
    return port.sendrecord(records);
}
```

}

using this code  i set the cacerts store for the overall process, so other parallel clients (like could be the case of Client1 and Client2 before) in the same process will use that setting.

But what if one of the other clients in the same process wants to have access to a different trust store?

How is it possible to change dynamically the trust store just for the single instance of the webservice client the way to don t affect the others? and to change it runtime as well?

Or

How can i have just one store and specify that client1 has to use certificate1 while client2 has to use certificate2 for the handshake?

Comment: Seems like you could dynamically figure out which `System.setProperty` based on the users request or something and determine the proper client store to use.  Not sure why your keystore and truststore are one in the same - thats not usually the norm...

Comment: what i m trying to do is to launch the same process running more parallel Thread. Each thread is a webservice client targeting different urls (https or http). This means that one client need to get 1 certificate, 1 client needs to have another different one (for the same server), one client doesn t need certificate at all.

Comment: How are you going to tell which certificate to use in the servers code, will the client pass something unique per client?

Comment: till now i don t know how to do it... this one of  the point of my question

Comment: It might be possible that you're over complicating things.  Unless you're using self signed certificates, which then need to be installed on the clients as trusted certs - you're going to be paying 75-150$ per domain name certificate - yearly.  If you're using self signed or even not self signed certificates - then that would be how you *could* deal with the situation.  Example: 1st client connects to yourdomain.com, second client connects to yourdomain2.com, third client connects to yourdomain3.com and fourth connects to yourdomain4.com.  In the code, first thing you check is the URL they...

Comment: ... connected with and then uses the appropriate keystore based on that URL.  But IMHO that may you cause you to have to intercept the request in the first place and then handle the SSL side of things in your code - possibly no easy feat as it's normally handled for you.  I think you might want to update your question with exactly why you're looking to do this, e.g the reasoning, the pro's and cons?

Comment: i m sorry but what i wrote, i mean the use cases... are requirements. I don t have control on the domain. The domain is unique and of third party. The third party provides us with different certification per client types... and it uses the CN in the certificate for its segregation policy. That s why i cannot skip it.

Comment: I may not fully understand, but your clients truststore, it can contain a 100 certificates that it trusts and then it can connect to a 100 different servers as they're all trusted in the keystore, it uses the correct certificate  to negotiate things

Comment: The requirements are:
-1 certificate TrustStore
- 1 secured endpoint to send requests to
- N certificates with N differents CN
- N clients inside the same java process using their own certificate each for sending their own data
- When the data arrive to the endpoint... the server uses the CN to store the data in a proper folder.
So my question is: how can i create N clients in the same java application sending data to the same endpoint but using different certificate for sending?